# error in interference code : Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, inference

I am trying to defined a TensorFlow model for ASL classification inference. It loads two saved models (feature_gen and model), makes them non-trainable, and i defined a call method for performing inference using the loaded models, and saves the Inference_Model instance as a saved model. But i keep getting the error below related to the call function, which runs the feture_gen model for preprocessing the data then its output should be fed to the ASL model for training. how can i fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Inference_Model(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Inference_Model, self).__init__()
        self.feature_gen = tf.saved_model.load('/kaggle/working/tf_Feature_generator')
        self.model = tf.saved_model.load('/kaggle/working/tf_model')
        self.feature_gen.trainable = False
        self.model.trainable = False
        
    @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 43], dtype=tf.float32, name='input')
    ])
    def call(self, input):
        output_tensors = {}
        features = self.feature_gen(**{'input': input})['output']
        print(features.shape)
        output_tensors['outputs'] = self.model(**{'input': tf.expand_dims(features, 0)})['output'][0,:]
        return output_tensors
    
my_tensorflow_model = Inference_Model()
tf.saved_model.save(my_tensorflow_model, '/kaggle/working/tf_inference_model', signatures={'serving_default': my_tensorflow_model.call})
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_31/303700862.py", line 18, in call  *
        output_tensors['outputs'] = self.model(**{'input': tf.expand_dims(features, 0)})['output'][0,:]

    ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (0 total):
        * 
      Keyword arguments: {'input': <tf.Tensor 'input:0' shape=(1, None) dtype=float32>}
    
     Expected these arguments to match one of the following 1 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (0 total):
        * 
      Keyword arguments: {'inputs': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2158), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')}
```

I tried to change the call input from `[None, 43]` to `[166, 43]` the input for the ASL model but i still get an error